# Add Commas Between Menu Items?

Tags: menus

I created a menu in wordpress in the Menus section of the backend is there any way to display the menu links with commas so it displays as `Link1, Link2, Link3, Link4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a very simple custom walker …

```
class WPSE_82726_Comma_Walker extends Walker
{
    public function walk( $elements, $max_depth )
    {
        $list = array ();

        foreach ( $elements as $item )
            $list[] = "<a href='$item->url'>$item->title</a>";

        return join( ', ', $list );
    }
}
```

… and call your menu like this:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array (
        'theme_location' => 'your_registered_theme_location',
        'walker'         => new WPSE_82726_Comma_Walker,
        'items_wrap'     => '<p class="menu">%3$s</p>'
    )
);
```

Fast and efficient. :)

Comment: where would I add this?

Comment: @JoeBobby The first part, the class, to your `functions.php`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, when declaring your `wp_nav_menu` function you do it like so;

```
$defaults = array(

    //for a full list of parameters see codex link below
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '<span class="comma">,</span>',

);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

Then in your WordPress menu under Appearance -> Menus, you will add a class name such as `nocomma` to the last menu item, in your case, **Link 4**...

[image]

...and in your CSS file you add,

```
.nocomma .comma {display:none;}
```

That's why we wrap the comma in a `<span>` tag. Of course there are other ways you could go about achieving your outcome but this is one of the more simple approaches to an equally simple problem.

Codex references:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: this has worked well up to the nocomma part, in wordpress I dont have the option to add the CSS Classes to the link, would it be because I'm adding `Custom Links`? I notice yours says `page` in the upper right: http://d.pr/i/Ow5J

Comment: Although you've selected an answer, for reference, on the same screen in **Appearance -> Menus** you can enable CSS classes on menu items by clicking the **Screen Options** link at the top right of screen and marking the CSS Classes checkbox accordingly. WordPress hides it by default.